# Angular 2 form validation, hasError is not a function

Tags: forms, validation, typescript, angular

i try to make a validation for my input fields.

this is a piece of code that I used:

**DepartmentComponent**

```
import {  
  FORM_DIRECTIVES,  
  FormBuilder,  
  ControlGroup,  
  Validators ,
   AbstractControl   
} from 'angular2/common';




@Component({
    selector: 'my-departments',
    providers: [HTTP_PROVIDERS, DepartmentService],
    directives: [FORM_DIRECTIVES, Alert],
    styleUrls: ['app/department.component.css'],
    templateUrl: 'app/department.component.html',
    pipes:[SearchPipe]

})

export class DepartmentComponent implements OnInit {
    myForm: ControlGroup;
    departmentName: AbstractControl;
    departmentLocation: AbstractControl;

    constructor(private _router: Router, private _departmentService: DepartmentService, fb: FormBuilder) { 

      this.myForm = fb.group({  
        'departmentName':  ['', Validators.required],
        'departmentLocation':  ['', Validators.required]  
      });

      this.departmentName= this.myForm.controls['departmentName'];  
      this.departmentLocation= this.myForm.controls['departmentLocation'];  
    }
```

**DepartmentComponent template**

```
   <form [ngFormModel]="myForm"  
          (ngSubmit)="addDepartment(newItem)" [hidden]="!showAddView" align="center">
        <div>       
            <label for="editAbrv">Department name:</label><br>
              <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="newItem.departmentName" [ngFormControl]="myForm.controls['departmentName']" > 

         <div *ngIf="departmentName.hasError('required')"  class="ui error message"><b style="color:red;">Name is required</b></div>  
      </div>

        <div>
            <label for="editAbrv">Department Location:</label><br>
             <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="newItem.departmentLocation" [ngFormControl]="myForm.controls['departmentLocation']" > 

         <div *ngIf="departmentLocation.hasError('required')" class="ui error message"><b style="color:red;">Location is required</b></div>  
      </div> 


        <div>
            <button type="submit" class="ui button">Submit</button>  
            <button><a href="javascript:void(0);" (click)="showHide($event)" >
                Cancel
            </a></button>
        </div>
</form>
```

The problem is that I got an error: .hasError is not a function. hasError function is in my html file (which you can see) I really don't see where I'm wrong. I did everything like is described in tutorial, but can't figure out why is this happen. Thanks for advice!

Comment: Try `*ngIf="departmentLocation?.hasError('required')"`

Comment: I solve it with this: *ngIf="myForm.controls['departmentName'].hasError('required')". I'm just not clear why does it works on this way :/

Comment: But these lines `this.departmentName= this.myForm.controls['departmentName'];` are inside the constructor? It isn't entirely clear from your code because there is an `}` missing.

Comment: Yes, these are inside my constructor, since that I thought I can use just departmentName, not the whole line:  this.myForm.controls['departmentName']; I don't think I missed }. I just didn't copy whole class implementation :)

Comment: Then the indentation is wrong (fixed it). It's too weird. I don't see why this wouldn't work.

Answer (score 10):

you should use `*ngIf="myForm.controls['departmentLocation'].hasError('required')"`

or any better luck with
`this.departmentName= this.myForm.controls.find('departmentName');` ?

Comment: it works when I use this.departmentName= this.myForm.controls.find('departmentName');. Really strange, since in tutorial I found this.departmentName= this.myForm.controls.find ['departmentName' ]; Thanks :)

Answer (score 8):

In place of `hasError` you should use `errors`

i.e it should be

```
myForm.controls['departmentLocation'].errors['required']
```

i.e with *ngIf

```
*ngIf="myForm.controls['departmentLocation'].errors['required']"
```

Comment: Using this approach, when the control is valid (so, `errors` is null), it shows me the next message: `Cannot read property 'required' of null`

Comment: quick trick could be to check error for not null(for condition when there is no error in control) i.e *ngIf="myForm.controls['departmentLocation'].errors 
 && myForm.controls['departmentLocation'].errors['required']"

Comment: to prevent not null error use this as `myForm.controls['departmentLocation'].errors?.required`

Comment: why don't people just use . notation it is so much easier to read.  I get the emphasis is on the [' --- '] but the reality is it is just an object and should be treated as such

Comment: btw the reason why this answer is mostly correct is because that is what is in the object.  If people could read objects this answer would have been easier to find for oneself

Answer (score 0):

This is similar to another answer I've provided here: [Form Builder with hasError() for validation throws an error of ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'hasError' of undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45328265/form-builder-with-haserror-for-validation-throws-an-error-of-error-typeerror/54082370#54082370).

The gist is that TypeScript getter's can be used to solve this in a clean way.

In your component class:

```
get departmentLocation() { 
    return this.myForm.get( 'departmentLocation' );
}
```

In your component template:

```
<input type="text" formControlName="departmentLocation">
<p class="ui error message" *ngIf="departmentLocation.hasError('required')">Department location is required</p>
```

Also important to note that using ngModel with Reactive Forms in Angular 6+ is depracated, so it's been removed from the examples above.

Answer (score 0):

i was getting compilation error for using

```
loginForm.get('email').hasError('required')
```

This fixed it

```
loginForm.get('email')?.hasError('required')
```

use it like this

```
<mat-error *ngIf="!loginForm.get('password')?.hasError('required')
          && loginForm.get('password')?.hasError('whitespace')">
```